# scaning bluetooth (java) on android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, realm

I am developing the attendance system using Bluetooth that allow the user to scan Bluetooth to get the Bluetooth address and compare it with registered Bluetooth address. The problem is, it only scan and display the registered list of student but not listing the available Bluetooth and also not compare with the register Bluetooth address.

here is the code for BluetoothScanActivity

```
public class BluetoothScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String TAG = BluetoothScanActivity.class.getSimpleName();

BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
IntentFilter filter;
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
String name[];
ArrayList<String> macID;
Bundle scan_data;
int countScans=0;
int numCountScans;
int value;
RippleBackground rippleBackground;

String classID;
boolean selectDateCheck = false;
Date selectedDate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth_scan);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.main_blue));
    }
    classID = getIntent().getStringExtra("Class ID");
    numCountScans = getIntent().getIntExtra("Number Scans",3);
    value = getIntent().getIntExtra("Value",1);
    selectDateCheck = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Manual Date",false);
    selectedDate = (Date)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Selected Date");
    Toast.makeText(this, numCountScans + " " + value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    rippleBackground = (RippleBackground)findViewById(R.id.content);

    int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

    init();
    if(mBluetoothAdapter==null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your device doesn't support bluetooth!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            turnOnBT();
        }
    }

    scan_data=new Bundle();
    name=new String[100];
    macID = new ArrayList<String>();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");
    searchDevices();
}
private void turnOnBT() {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
}
public void init()
{

    mBluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


    //Create a BroadCastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    mReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action=intent.getAction();
            //When discovery finds a device
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals((action)))
            {
                //Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device=intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                //Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                if(!macID.contains(device.getAddress().toUpperCase()))
                    macID.add(device.getAddress().toUpperCase());
                Toast.makeText(context,device.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals((action)))
            {
                if(mBluetoothAdapter.getState()== BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF) {
                    turnOnBT();
                }
            }
            else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals((action)))
            {
                if(countScans == numCountScans-1)
                {
                    rippleBackground.stopRippleAnimation();
                    Intent in = new Intent(BluetoothScanActivity.this, MarkStudentsActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra("Class ID", classID);
                    in.putExtra("Value",value);
                    in.putStringArrayListExtra("MAC ID's", macID);
                    intent.putExtra("Manual Date",selectDateCheck);
                    intent.putExtra("Selected Date",selectedDate);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    countScans++;
                    Log.d("Mark","" + countScans);
                    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    filter=new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
    if(mBluetoothAdapter!=null)
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Comment: No, Android **Studio** doesn't support Bluetooth.

Comment: is it for real???

Comment: Android Studio is an IDE not Android OS. Why did you tag Android Studio IDE tag?

Comment: but I am running my project on android studio platform